# C#,HTML how can i populate html text box with values saved in session or values handled at server side?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have some textbox values in aspx page,which i pass on to the next page using sessions,but now i want to populate these values in a html textbox .How can i do it?The values that i have are server side ,where as HTML text box value is client side(this is just my assumption,i can be totally wrong on this part).

The reason why i want to do this is i got code from the internet which gives location,map between two points,the directions between the source and destination,but it is using html textbox and i think it is using ajax (i have 0 knowledge of ajax) so if i replace html textbox with asp.net text box .I dont get the auto address completion feature .

the aspx page is ,i am not able to understand the java script here cause it is very complex for me:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source, destination;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
    });

    function GetRoute() {
        var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(27.4667, 89.6417);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: mumbai
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

        //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

        var request = {
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

        //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

            } else {
                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
            }
        });
    }
</script>

          <input type="text" id="txtSource"  style="width: 315px" /> 
           &nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style4">Destination:&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="txtDestination" style="width: 318px" />
        <br />
        &nbsp;<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" style="margin-left: 437px" />
```

Can anyone please help me out with this .

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the the values directly into the html textbox using embedded code, this is done in the .aspx file **not** the code behind (aspx.cs):

```
<input type="text"><%= Session[""].ToString() %></input>
```

more information on embedded code blocks:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: i used this method,but now i am having two text boxes side by side ,with no way to modify the session value  and i double checked it only one entry for html text box was given .I am updating my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as input text box

```
<input type="text" id="inputtextbox"/>
```

Using Javascript you can assign the data in session in to input text box

```
document.getelementbyid("inputtextbox").value = <%= Session[""].ToString() %>
```

Comment: getting syntax error        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination').value = <%= Session["toaddress"].ToString() %>);

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have a HTML textbox like this:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
```

To access it from code-behind without any help from javascript, you can simple add `runat="server"` to the textbox and it can be called from code-behind.

So, it becomes something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" runat="server" />
```

And you can do like this to add it to the textbox from code-behind:

```
text1.Text = Session[""].ToString();
```

Tip: Always check to see if session is null before applying the value .

Comment: I did this way before ,problem is the built in fucntionality of text box that is auto address completion is getting diabled if i use the runat="server" code for the  textbox